# VBA function for Upside/Downside Capture

Tags: excel, vba, function, range, offset

apologies for my ignorance, I'm brand new to VBA - I'm sure this is a simple problem...
I'm trying to write a fn. for up/down side capture in VBA.  This is the problem:
There are two columns.  One has fund performance in % (I've labelled 'returns').  The other has index performance in % (labelled 'index').  Both are same length / same number of rows.  I need both to be variables to enter to the fn.

For UpsideCapture fn., for all nos. in the index column >0, I want to find the corresponding number in the returns column (which will be on the same row).  Once I have those numbers I can compound them.
I've tried using Offset, assuming the returns column is 15 columns to the left of the index column but it doesn't return anything, and I don't really want to rely on it always being 15 columns apart (it arbitrary).

Many thanks!

One of my rubbish attempts is below.  Any help is much appreciated.  Its really just a case of finding the correct corresponding row based on the value in the index column...

```
Function UpsideCapture(returns As Range, index As Range) As Variant
 
Dim n As Integer
Dim m As Integer
Dim i As Integer

n = returns.Rows.Count
m = index.Rows.Count

For i = 1 To m
   If index(i) > 0 Then
     Upsidecap = ((1 + Upsidecap) * (1 + Offset(returns(i), -15))) - 1
   End If
Next

UpsideCapture = Upsidecap
 
End Function
```

example

[image: test_data]

Comment: Can you provide some example data and the desired result?

Comment: yes sure, sorry i should have included originally

Comment: column 1 is "returns", column 2 is "index".  If value in column 2 >0, Then i want to return the corresponding value in column 1, then for each value returned, equivalent of PRODUCT(1 + column 1 returned range)-1

Comment: I meant you to [edit] it and show some screenshot or add some actual data so whe have a [mcve] of your problem that we can reproduce.

Comment: Date         returns index returns if index>0  
28-Feb-22 1.76% -2.70%                             
31-Jan-22 0.80% -4.96%   
31-Dec-21 0.53% 3.90% 0.53%  
30-Nov-21 -0.06% -2.51%   
31-Oct-21 0.19% 5.03% 0.19%  
30-Sep-21 0.34% -4.28%   
31-Aug-21 0.90% 2.36% 0.90%  
31-Jul-21        -0.43% 0.59% -0.43%  
30-Jun-21 -1.54% 1.20% -1.54%  
31-May-21 0.21% 1.37% 0.21%  
30-Apr-21 0.15% 4.24% 0.15%  
31-Mar-21 0.80% 2.46% 0.80%

Comment: Please [edit] your original question instead of posting comments. They are pretty useless without formatting.

Comment: sorry i have added picture of an example in the original post (test_data)

Comment: And how do you call the function? What is `returns As Range` and `index As Range` when you call it?

Comment: Returns as range and index as range I want to be dynamic.  I'm going to handle this by using INDIRECT R1C1 in excel.  The user can use the Function as: UpsideCapture(returns, index) in excel.  I will replace "returns' and "index" in the actual formula in excel with an INDIRECT formula which i can control the arguments for.  the INDIRECT formulae will reference different date ranges for example to change the length of the columns (i hope that makes sense)

Comment: Can you please show the exact use of the formula on the data you show in the screenshot and tell what the outcome is, and what the outcome is that you expected? It doesn't help if you tell the use can use it like `UpsideCapture(returns, index)` we need one concrete example how you used it to understand what is going wrong.